# How to add particular raw_input responses to subclasses in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, if-statement, subclass

I am learning Python by writing a simple text RPG, and I'd like to make certain choices available to the player regardless of what room they are in. Rather than doing...

```
health = 100

def room():
    while True:
        response = raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
        if any(x in response for x in ("life", "health")):
            print health
        elif "continue" in response:
            room1_1()
        else:
            pass

def room1_1():
    while True:
        response = raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
        if any(x in response for x in ("life", "health")):
            print health
        elif "continue" in response:
            room1_2()
        else:
            pass

room()
```

and continually writing if statements for things like "life", "inventory", etc., I'd like to be able to have a general "room" class that allows for particular raw_input responses and subclasses that allow for those responses, plus specific responses for different rooms. Ultimately, my question is: if I create a function within a class...

```
class Room:

    def enter(self):
        while True:
            response = raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
            if any(x in response for x in ("life", "health")):
                print health
            else:
                pass
```

How can I enable a subclass to accept "life" and "health" as responses, but also accept different inputs that the parent class isn't sensitive to (eg, "open door to my left", "check the drawer", "foo this bar" etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
class Action(object):
    pass


class HealthAction(Action):
    triggers = ("life", "health")

    def perform(self):
        print health


class Room(object):
    actions = [HealthAction()] # this list contains actions applicable to all rooms
    room_actions = [] # this list contains room-specific actions

    def enter(self):
        while True:
            response = raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
            for action in self.actions + self.room_actions:
                if any(x in response for x in action.triggers):
                    action.perform()

class RoomOne(Room):
    room_actions = [] # you can add room-specific actions here
```

Note that having `health` as a global variable may not be such a good idea but you could introduce a `Player` class to keep track of various properties of the player.

Comment: Ah, cool, I like this, thank you. Quick (possibly naive) question. If I have information like a player's health or stats within the Player class, am I able to modify those variables outside the scope of that class? For instance, if I have an enemy dealing damage to the player (the enemy itself probably a subclass of the class Enemy), can I have an attack function within the Enemy class return some value, and do something like 'player.health -= enemy.attack()'?

Comment: That all depends on how you want to model things. But you can indeed have `player.health -= enemy.attack()` or even `enemy.attack(player)` where the `attack` method modifies the player's characteristics, such as health but perhaps also stamina and other things (stealing inventory etc).